# I want to pass variables to another page using the session storage and it give me java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, web

I'm pretty new to programming and i encountered this problem i have search internet and couldn't find the answer i was looking for. Hope you can help me here. Thanks!

I'm trying to pass 2 variables which is the name and custid.
(i'm using mysql workbench as my database).

I'm guessing my error is something to do with.

```
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String password=request.getParameter("password");
```

---

here's my code:

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Resource(name="jdbc/eg3752")
    private DataSource usercatalogue;
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {

        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");

        Connection connection=null;
        Statement statement=null;
        ResultSet resultset=null;

        String login="SELECT * FROM customer where email='"+email+"'";

        try
        {
            connection=usercatalogue.getConnection();
            statement=connection.createStatement();
            resultset=statement.executeQuery(login);
            while(resultset.next())
                    {
                      // check if password is same in the database
                        if(password.equals(resultset.getString("password")))
                        {
                            HttpSession session =request.getSession();
                            session.setAttribute("name", resultset.getString("fullname"));
                            session.setAttribute("custid", resultset.getString("customerId"));
                            response.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/search.html");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/login.html");
                        }
                    }



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error on the GlassFish Server 4

```
Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:518)
    at com.aleksi.loginServlet.doPost(loginServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the "caused by" sections of the stack trace, which are the important part.

An IllegalStateException on a sendRedirect() has to do with the HTTP protocol and occurs when the response to the client has already been committed.  This will usually happen when either the response buffer has reached max size or someone has called flush() explicitly or written something to the output stream and caused the response to be committed.

After calling `sendRedirect()` add `return;` and then try.